# Sans-serif font identification

Tags: font-identification

I need to know the name of this font:

[image]

Does anybody recognize it? I'm pretty sure it's the same font used in ICBC's logo and branding, which you can see at http://stuross.ca/icbc-branding/.

I've tried both [identifont](http://www.identifont.com) and [whatthefont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) with no success :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, it is the same as ICBC's logo. It's hard to see, but in the screenshot of their brand guidelines they note that they use [Gotham](http://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/styles/). Your example is using Gotham Bold.

[image]

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Comment: @Darth_Vader Added.

Comment: and you get rewarded..

Comment: Also featured for all in-movie posters in "V for Vendetta". That's probably unrelated to ICBC, though.